# Facebook login (JavaScript) suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, authentication

I've been using the following JavaScript to log my users in via Facebook. It has been working fine for a few weeks, but all of a sudden it stopped working.

When I click the login button the regular Facebook connection window is opening, but when I've logged in the session seems to remain unset.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({appId: 'MY_APP_ID',cookie: true,xfbml: true,channelUrl: 'http://MYURL.com/channel.php',oauth: true});};
(function() {var e = document.createElement('script');
e.async = true;e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);}());

function CallAfterLogin(){
        FB.login(function(response) {       
        if (response.status === "connected") 
        {
            LodingAnimate(); //Animate login
            FB.api('/me', function(data) {

                window.location = 'http://MYURL.com/<?=$_SESSION['lang']; ?>';

          });
         }
    });
}

</script>
```

Code in **channel.php**:

```
<?php
$cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
?><script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does using `<?php=$_SESSION['lang']; ?>` do? (adding `php`).

Comment: Well, I doubt it has anything to do with the error, but it contains the language the user has chosen.

Comment: have you tried debugging it with firebug console or google chrome developer tools?

Comment: I get a few errors, this is one of them:
FB.login() called when user is already connected.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should handle the user status:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : 'MY_APP_ID', // App ID
              channelUrl : 'http://MYURL.com/channel.php', // Channel File
              status     : true, // check login status
              cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });

            // Additional initialization code here
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
               FB.api('/me', function(data) {

                window.location = 'http://MYURL.com/<?=$_SESSION['lang']; ?>';

               });
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                //you must ask permissions to the user
            } else {
                //user is not logged, just change the scope for the ones you want or remove
                //it if you don't need any additional permissions
                FB.login(function(response) { }, {scope:'email,user_likes'}); 
            }
        });
        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
</script>
```

**EDIT**

This is the current code of your page

```
<body>

<div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset"><div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px;"><div><iframe name="fb_xdm_frame_http" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" id="fb_xdm_frame_http" aria-hidden="true" title="Facebook Cross Domain Communication Frame" tab-index="-1" style="border: none;" src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=21#channel=f2c633f99&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Ftictam.com&amp;channel_path=%2Fse%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Dfd496acc4%26"></iframe><iframe name="fb_xdm_frame_https" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" id="fb_xdm_frame_https" aria-hidden="true" title="Facebook Cross Domain Communication Frame" tab-index="-1" style="border: none;" src="https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=21#channel=f2c633f99&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Ftictam.com&amp;channel_path=%2Fse%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Dfd496acc4%26"></iframe></div></div><div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px;"><div><iframe name="f68921bbc" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" style="display: none;" src="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&amp;response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&amp;display=none&amp;domain=tictam.com&amp;origin=1&amp;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D21%23cb%3Df1f63150cc%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Ftictam.com%252Ff2c633f99%26domain%3Dtictam.com%26relation%3Dparent&amp;sdk=joey"></iframe></div></div></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sv_SE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>




<div id="intro_form" style="margin-top: -2px; top: 0px; position: fixed; z-index: 100; min-height: 50px;">

    <a href="/se"><img src="/logo3.png" style="margin-bottom: -19px;" border="0"></a>

<form method="post" action="/se/find" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; clear: none; display: inline;" id="search_form">
   <input type="text" name="what" placeholder="Vad?" value=""> <input type="text" name="where" placeholder="Var?" value=""> <input type="submit" name="search" id="intro_submit" value="Sök!" style="width: 224px !important; cursor: pointer; margin-right: 4px;"> 
   </form>


   <form method="post" action="/se/find" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; clear: none; display: none; margin-top: 20px;" id="search_form_2">
   <input type="text" name="what" placeholder="Vad?" value=""> <input type="text" name="where" placeholder="Var?" value=""> <input type="submit" name="search" id="intro_submit" value="Sök!" style="width: 224px !important; cursor: pointer; margin-right: 4px;"> 
   </form>

   <img src="/search-icon.png" width="35" height="35" id="search_icon" style="display: none; margin-top: 11px; margin-right: 11px; float: right; clear: both;">


    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        if ( $(window).width() < 900) 
        {
            $("#search_form").hide();
            $("#search_icon").show();
        }
    });

    $("#search_icon").click(function()
    {
        $("#search_form_2").toggle("slow");
    });

    </script>

    <div style="height: 50px;"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : '360183997416092', // App ID
              channelUrl : 'http://tictam.com/channel.php', // Channel File
              status     : true, // check login status
              cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });

            // Additional initialization code here
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
               FB.api('/me', function(data) {

                window.location = 'http://tictam.com/se';

               });
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                //you must ask permissions to the user
            } else {
                //user is not logged, just change the scope for the ones you want or remove
                //it if you don't need any additional permissions
                FB.login(function(response) { }, {scope:'email, user_work_history, user_education_history'}); 
            }
        });
        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
</script>
```

As you can see right next to the `<body>` tag you're loading a a javascript sdk, and then at bottom you're loading again using my code, remove the first one and move my code next to the `<body>` tag

Comment: Now it tells me the application ID isn't correct, which it is (believe me, I've checked)

Comment: wow, if it says that it must have a reason, are you sure that you have everything right? does your project is online so I can check it?

Comment: after <div id="fb-root"></div> you're loading another facebook sdk remove it

Comment: are you sure? I'm still seeing it online

Comment: I've edited my answer check it, so you can spot where you're loading the sdk again

Comment: I followed your instructions. Now it seems like it has entered an infinite page refreshing loop...

Comment: I've tested it and you still have some errors. Your facebook login button is calling a function that does not exist onlogin="javascript:CallAfterLogin();

Comment: Right, removed it now. Same problem though... :/

Comment: thats because on the response==connected you do a refresh window.location = 'http://tictam.com/se'; what to you intend to do when the user is logged and has already granted permissions?

Comment: Well, since I'm removing the refreshing code in the back end by checking if $user is set, it should be fine... But it appears as if the $user variable isn't being set :/ (I'm using the regular Facebook SDK for the authentication)